# Use the digits 1, 9, 9, 8 to get 81

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Using the digits $1, 9, 9$ and $8$ in that order, and the operations $+$, $-$ and/or $\times$ in any order between pairs of digits, create an expression that equals $81$. 
Normal precedence rules apply.

As an example, here is one solution: $1 \times 9 + 9 \times 8 = 81$. Find three or four more solutions that fit the criteria.

Comment: Paris of digits?

Comment: @zagad: Probably a typo of "pairs of digits".

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Oh, right! I just couldn't figure out what the auto-corrector corrected here :)

Comment: @KeykoYume: But ++ is a different operator than +. And - in -1 is the unary negation operator, not sure if that is allowed either.

Comment: Are you sure this is possible without division or concatenation? Or am I misinterpreting the instructions and you are allowed to do those?

Comment: It is unclear what is allowed. Are parentheses allowed? What about **and** **or**? Are only $+ - \times$ allowed? You ask for "three of four more solutions." Do they exist?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling!  Unfortunately, the rules for this site require that a question have criteria for determining a single, optimal, correct answer.  While there may be multiple valid answers, you must specify what you consider the *best* answer (least operations used, numbers in increasing order, ???).  A question asking for "three or four more solutions" is by definition too broad for this site.  If you can modify the question to give criteria for a selecting a single best answer, please do so, and then flag the question for reopening by a mod.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If truly only + - X are accepted, no parenthesis or concatenations, and the numbers must stay in this order, all I can see for now are those.

> 1 x 9 + 9 x 8 = 81
>  -1 x -9 + 9 x 8 = 81
>  1 x 9 + -9 x -8 = 81
>  -1 x -9 + -9 x -8 = 81

Comment: Well done I completely forgot about using negatives. Not sure if its what they wanted but it works!

Comment: That's most simple and correct answer,  well done

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of using negatives, because the question says "in any order _between pairs of digits_"... I guess if the OP says it's correct, then it is!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is considered cheating or not but would these solutions count?

> ((-1-9)*9-8)--

or:

> ((-1+9)*9+8)++

or:

> ((19-9)*8)++

Comment: Probably not: ++ and -- are not the same operators as + and -. IOW, it is probably cheating and invalid.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis yeah, I think you're right

Answer (score 1):

Another answer to this question is:

> 9*8*1+9

I'm also pretty sure that that is the only other answer. Here's why:

> To get 81, we need to get any of the following: 80, 81, or 82 with 9,9,8; 9, 72, or 90 with 1,8,9; or 73 or 89 with 9,9,1. Let's start with 9,9,1. The closest we can come to 73 is 9*(9-1) = 72. Likewise, we also miss 89 by one, with 9*(9+1) = 90. Any other combination either gives a number in the 80s or number that is too small. Continuing with 1,8,9, it *is* possible to get 72 in one of the two ways (that we have already said.) Getting 9 is impossible; your numbers are either too high or too low (9+1-8) = 2, 9+8-1 = 16). The highest possible number to get by using 1,8,9 with your rules is 9*(8+1) = 81, so 90 is out of the question. Finally, 9, 9, 8. At first glance, it seems possible to get 81 (9*8+9), but this solution is the same as the solutions from 72 with 1,8,9. Also, it's not possible to get 80 or 82, because the only way to get close is 9*9 or 9*8. 9*9 is 81, which + or -8 doesn't help; and 9*8 + 9 is 81, which we've covered. So, the only two (eight with negative numbers) possible solutions with your rules are 9*8*1+9 and 9*8+9*1.

Comment: Well done! The question does technically says that you have to keep the order of the digits as 1-9-9-8

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming by 'and or' you mean bitwise and or

Following is a possible solution:

> 1 or 9 x 9 or 8=81, bitwise has higher precedence than x

Comment: lol, but it doesn't have the lateral-thinking tag so I doubt that this is the correct answer.